# Is "condition" followed by "where" "that", or "in that"?

Tags: nouns, relative-clauses

> The system sounds an alarm when a condition is met **where/that/in**
>   **that** the temperature exceeds a preset value.

I would like to know which of "where" "that", and "in that" is correct for the above sentence, although you may feel that the portion "a condition is met where/that/in" is unnecessary and needs to be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I would simply drop the phrase completely:

> The systems sounds an alarm when [] the temperature exceeds a preset value*.

That seems the most natural to me.

---

However, if I were to keep the extra verbiage, I wouldn't use any of the phrases you suggest but something slightly different:

> The systems sounds an alarm when *a condition is met* ***in which*** the temperature exceeds a preset value.

---

In the blog post ["'Where' Versus 'In Which',"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/where-versus-in-which) Bonnie Mills says this:

> Many times, you can add a preposition before the relative pronoun “which” to make your sentence quite precise. For example, “The house at which I saw you” has a slightly different meaning from “The house in which I saw you.” If you use “where,” you lose the subtle distinction: “The house where I saw you.”

In this particular sentence, the alarm sounds *when* a condition is met—unlike in the blog post example that references a spatial location with *where*. At least one of the things that happens during this condition is that the temperature exceeds a preset value. So this temperature increase is *part of* the condition. (It may or may not be the only thing that happens). Because of this, *in which* more specifically conveys that sense.